# Is there any way for windows batch script or command prompt to list the directories from a certain folder only without including the hard drive?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I tried using `dir /b/s *.png`  to list the directories of all my png files. the results were like this:

```
D:\Newfolder\test\images\approved\11.png
D:\Newfolder\test\images\approved\12.png
D:\Newfolder\test\images\approved\13.png
D:\Newfolder\test\images\approved\14.png
D:\Newfolder\test\images\approved\15.png
D:\Newfolder\test\images\approved\16.png
D:\Newfolder\test\images\approved\17.png
D:\Newfolder\test\images\approved\18.png
D:\Newfolder\test\images\approved\19.png
D:\Newfolder\test\images\approved\20.png
```

I want it to be shortened so it will display only starting from the ***images*** folder;

```
images\approved\11.png
images\approved\12.png
images\approved\13.png
images\approved\14.png
images\approved\15.png
images\approved\16.png
images\approved\17.png
images\approved\18.png
images\approved\19.png
images\approved\20.png
```

is it possible to do?
if it's not, is there any way for me to edit the directories by deleting the first few folder from a generated text file?

say i put `dir /b/s *.png > path.txt` how do i edit the texts since the list got no whitespaces.

i'm still new to this so i'm not so familiar with much commands but this is as far as my understanding can do.

Comment: If the images folder is always the 2nd child, an approach like so can be used in creating the text file: `@For /F "Tokens=3,* Delims=:\" %%G in ('Dir /B /S D:\Newfolder\test\images\*.png') Do @Echo/%%~H`

Comment: @T3RR0R and what happens when the files are in `D:\NewFolder\Newfolder\test\images\approved`

Comment: As stated, If the images folder is always the 2nd child

Comment: @T3RR0R, problem is this line in the question: _"I want it to be shortened so it will display only starting from the __images__ folder;"_ We can therefore never be sure what the structure is prior to `\images..`

Comment: Fitri Idrus, can you please clarify the issue you are experiencing, it seems as if you're looking for the relative paths. What is the current directory when you're invoking your `dir` command? Is it `D:\Newfolder\test`, _(or more likely `C:\Users\UserName`)_?

Comment: it wont always be the 2nd child since i'm gonna use those data on several computers so the root path will always be different

Comment: @T3RR0R i see your suggestion. For different paths, all i need to do is just edit the tokens part. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this comment in your question:

> *"I want it to be shortened so it will display only starting from the **"images"** folder;*"

you always want from the images folder, and also assuming the images folder always exists in the path:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R %%i in (*.png) do (
   set "_fp=%%~i"
   echo !_fp:*\images\=images\!"
)
pause
```

Or to explicitly ensure you only include paths with `\images\` in the path:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s *.png ^| findstr \images\') do (
   set "_fp=%%~i"
   echo !_fp:*\images\=images\!"
)
pause
```

example of using pushd:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "%~1"
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s *.png ^| findstr \images\') do (
   set "_fp=%%~i"
   echo !_fp:*\images\=images\!"
)
pause
popd
```

So the above you can run from `cmd` and simply pass the path you want the script to run in as `script_name.cmd "C:\some path\here"`

Comment: i tried this but i'm not sure how `!var!` is used in cmd because i even tried with simple code it only echoes the exact words back, not the values/contents of it. So, I changed it to `%var%` instead. the problem is the results only shows one same results for each existing loops. say i got 10 png files, the result is 10 repetition but with the same file name for each loop.

Comment: Well, you tagged batch file, so copy this code, open `notepad.exe` paste it, then goto file, save as, change the file type to all files, then save the file with a `.cmd` extension. something like `my_images.cmd` Obviously save it in the root where you want to search from, then browse via explorer, find the file and double click it..

Comment: ahh i see it now. my bad for not being thorough. it works in batch files. however, i would like to put it in a text file so it can be read by other program. so how can i make the `images` folder to be the folder where i will put this .bat file? so it will list all .png files in the particular folder including the subfolders too

Comment: you can put it in any root folder lower than the actual folder, so even if it is `"c:\users\user\documents\my files\images\some other\etc.png"` you can place it in any folder from `C:` to `my files` and it will do the same. You could obviously use `pushd` to tell it where to go to, even if the file remains in one place.

Comment: i mean if i want it from a different folder name, is there any other way besides changing the word `images` in the code?

Comment: well, the script needs to know at which folder you want it to stop at, so you need to specify a folder somewhere! But it is also important to understand that you cannot ask a question and keep changing the scope of your requirement, you asked how to and specifically mentioned `images` folder, asking additional questions in the comments is not how it works here. I have already spent the time to give a solution to provide exactly what you asked in the initial quesiton.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the insights though. I will take note for that.